# Could anyone please help me in understanding how the authors calculated "SMB-hedged with QMJ" at page number 489 of the paper?

Tags: factor-models, factor-loading

Link for the paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X18301326.
"Size matters if you control your junk" by Asness et al. (2018)
It's Figure 1.

Comment: SMB returns are correlated to QMJ returns (as well as several other factors).  Correlated negatively: the typical small stock is quite junky. To hedge these factors out means to form a portfolio $r_{SMB}+\cdots+\beta_{QMJ} \cdot r_{QMJ}$ where the Betas are chosen such that the result is uncorrelated with QMJ (and the other factors listed). Hope This Helps.

Comment: @noob2 I got the intuition behind it. But still confused as to how can I exactly calculate it. Right now, I have monthly time-series data for SMB, HML, UMD, RmRf, and QMJ and I have the estimated factor loadings of rest of the 4 factors when they are regressed on SMB. So, are you suggesting I should multiply the loadings and returns of each factor and then add the result with the returns of SMB?

Comment: I *believe* (but I have not done this calculation) that the estimated factor loadings on the 4 factors are what is used (with a sign change) as the coefficients I called the Betas. For example if the loading of QMJ regressed on SMB is -0.3 then you form r_SMB+0.3*r_QMJ

Comment: In figure 1, they mention this statement: "Fig. 1 shows the impact of controlling for quality or junk on the size effect by examining SMB hedged with respect to the market, its lagged value, and HML and UMD factors and using the composite QMJ factor." I suppose this means I have to include all the other betas as well and not just QMJ. Anyways, I will try to replicate the results of the paper using both methods and get back to you. Thanks.!

Comment: Yes, that is why i have $+\cdots+$ in my pseudo equation above, those are the other Betas there in that space in the middle before QMJ.

Comment: In your example above, if the loading of QMJ is -0.3, you have mentioned a plus sign in the equation. Why would there be a plus sign? Shouldn't that be a minus? Is it a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you have to *undo* the QMJ component, hence the opposite sign.

Comment: Alright. Is it because we are essentially filtering out the junky component from the universe of small stocks? And, I am also supposing that the sign change is only in QMJ factor, right?

Comment: @noob2 Hey mate, thank you very much for the help. It worked..!